# Download Excel file with as is filename in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I download Excel file with as is filename returned by the service in my `Angular` application? I'm using `file-saver` library. Here is my code:

```
let blob = new Blob([response],  {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
saveAs(blob, 'hello.xlsx');
```

This is the response of Angular service:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.reportsUrl}`, { responseType: 'blob'});
```

Response of my backend service (Spring MVC). `excelCreatedResource` is of type `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"" + excelCreateResource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(excelCreateResource);
```

I don't want to supply `hello.xlsx`. Instead, I would just like to download the file without changing the filename returned by the service. If I access the URL directly from browser, I am able to download the Excel file.

Comment: What is the structure of the response of your service?

Comment: will you please add response snippet to understand your question more better way

Comment: I guess you could slice the name from `this.reportsUrl`. The other option would be to request the file name to be send in the response you get from this API.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question I think you need to observe complete response and get the header details from it. In Angular you can do this by using

```
let observable$ = this.http.get(`${this.reportsUrl}`, { observe: 'response'});
observable$.subscribe(response => {
  let blobObj = response.body; // this should be your blob object (body of response)
  let headers = response.Headers //This is a disctionary/HashMap were you'll find the content-desposition header

//.....

})
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: For this: `let filename = response.headers.get('filename');
        let body = response.body;
        var blob = new Blob([body],  {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
        saveAs(blob, filename);`

Comment: How to tell that it would consume blob, coz it says: `error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"`

Comment: No more error. But the problem is I cant get the filename. It returns `null`.

Comment: Thank you. I exactly followed your codes and I added @Zarna Borda suggestion. Both your answers complete the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `excelCreateResource.getFilename();` return a filename then, you can store file name in a local variable and pass this variable in `saveAs()` method like:

```
var filename = excelCreateResource.getFilename();
saveAs(blob, filename );
```

Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: `excelCreateResource` is Java object, not JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a File constructor without specifying a filename. The File itself already contains a name.

`let blob = new Blob([response],  {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformatofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
saveAs(blob);`

or you have to fetch the headers from your response , save the filename in variable  and pass the variable to saveAs() function.

Comment: Default it will download file as download.xlsx. Add 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition' in your backend response header. Get the file name from response header. and pass that filename to saveAs()

Comment: Thank you. Finally, my issue got resolved. I just don't know which answer I would accept. @Ankesh answer is also of great help. I exactly followed it and I added your suggestion. Both your answers complete the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using library FileSaverJs

```
let wbout = <write output> // write table or json to excell
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  }
  return buf;
}
// Save it as test.xlsx
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'hello.xlsx');
```

Comment: Like I said I  don't want to supply filename in the client, like `hello.xlsx`.

Comment: you say what you don't want, but not what you want.

Comment: Really? Di you not read this line? `I don't want to supply hello.xlsx. Instead, I would just like to download the file without changing the filename returned by the service. If I access the URL directly from browser, I am able to download the Excel file.`

Comment: Besides, if really I did not say what I wanted, but clearly I said what I don't want. Therefore, the least thing you can do is not to suggest what I don't want. You should have asked, if you did not understand my post.